# Looking to install Ubuntu on SSD and reaplace Win10 from SSD

Tags: ssd

I'm completly new to ubuntu and I'm looking to install it on my 120GB Samsung SSD and replace Windows 10 which is currently on SSD. Is there anything I should do or know before starting the instalation, wanna alocate all the space for ubuntu, not looking to add any other new OS. Any tips is highly apreciated ,ty!

EDIT: I needed to press 'e' in the installer menu and replace 'aqua spalsh' (or something like this) with 'nomodeset' before installing it!

Comment: no, there's no chance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing most Modern Operating systems is very seamless when using the default.  The difficulties (for some) come when trying to install multiple OSes on the same hard drive.

For Ubuntu, just download the `iso` installation image from the [official site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download).  Transfer it to a media (DVD or USB drive) and run boot to it.

Since you are using a new computer (shipped with Windows 10) you have the UEFI or Legacy options to choose from.  You can use either.  If you choose UEFI your disk can not be booted no many older than 5 years.  Other than that it really doesn't matter whether you use UEFI or not.  For convenience your can check the options of Downloading updates and installing third party software.  If you skip checking those options, it's very easy to download them after Ubuntu is installed.

**Install Type**

You'll have the two main options.  One is to install alongside the previous detected OSes.

In your case you'll be using the full disk.  So choose the option. Erase disk and install Ubuntu.

The install process will ask you for a Username and Password and seamlessly install Ubuntu.  The process would be very similar to when you first unboxed your brand new Windows 10 machine and turned it on.  You answer a few questions, then you'll be booted into the Brand New OS to login with you chosen Username and password.

There is a Gear icon at the top right of the screen.  You can click on that for help and tips.

---

By the way, there are many similarities between Operating systems (Windows, IOS and Linux).  They all have a default home directory for the user's personal content.  On Windows your default home directory is `/users/yourusername`.  In `Ubuntu` your default home directory is `/home/yourusername`.  If save a file pictures are anything personal you can browse that area to find your personal data.

Comment: I ran the installer and it started to freeze, now I see the ubuntu logo and 5 white dots below, after that it doesn't run anymore :(

Comment: When you say it started to freeze, how long did you leave it inactive.  What  title bar of the Windows that was frozen.  I'm looking at an example on my computer, the last detailed step of my answer was on a window with `Install (as superuser)` in the title bar.  Depending on what it's actually doing, some of the sections take a little while during the install process.

Comment: It's been more that half a hour, this is what I get on the screen, but with WHITE dots ... http://s1243.photobucket.com/user/squiffyk7/media/Ubuntuscreen.png.html

Comment: Are you saying the media didn't boot?  When you say ran the installer, did you get to any of the prompts, or it just didn't boot at any of the prompts.  If the later is the case, you may have to set a boot option in your computer's bios.  Did you ever see any words on the screen when you attempted to boot to the media?

Comment: I didn't run the installerul You are right, I opend the boit menu, clicked on the USB, poped up some text and crashed there,  the installer from ubuntu installation Guide didn't poped up..do u know at least how can I quit the installation, maybe I neted to make some setting in boot mode..ctrl c/break, esc dont work

Comment: Just reboot the computer.  There are `read/write` files opened.  So shutting down the computer won't corrupt anything.

Comment: Great, the reboot key doesn't shut it down..is there any chances for the keyboard to get unrecognized?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45660/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-razvan-alex).

Answer (score 0):

If you system only uses an SSD there are not a lot of tips.

It might be wise to create an extra partition (besides /) and use a /data/ (I use /discworld/ myself) partition for your personal files and put the directories in /home/$USER/ on that partition (see `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`).
That makes backup up easy: you either make a full backup (system, settings, personal files) or just a personal backup.

Makes it easier to re-install too. My personal files are on an extra HDD in my notebook and I only need to mount it during a re-install (and copy `/discworld/user-dirs.dirs` to `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`).

Check for compatibility with Linux and make sure trim is supported for your SSD. Samsung should be OK though so that one is covered.

Just do it :)

Comment: I ran the installer and it started to freeze, now I see the ubuntu logo and 5 white dots below, after that it doesn't run anymore :(