# I can't install ubuntu, no caching folder found

Tags: boot

First of all I'm looking to install ubuntu, after I made 2 bootable USB's to make sure, I still got the same error. I'm not really is sure If it's caused by the bios or USB. This is what I get when I try to boot from usb and try it live.. I really need help, I have no functioning os left on my asus rog laptop.

Error here:

[image]

Comment: Different error

Comment: @RazvanAlex The errors are identical.

Comment: I don't even know what to do now, I on mobile..

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu did you create?

Comment: LTS version....

Comment: Is the LTS `12.04`, `14.04`, or `16.04`?  The UEFI support isn't the same for `LTS` previous to `16.04`.

Comment: When I go on ubuntu.com, download section, it download me 16.04.1 LTS, I can't choose

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what it can be, but I can suggest:

First, "No caching mode page found" is irrelevant. It shows up every time I boot my NAS and it works perfectly.

Second, and most likely, the image file you make those boot USB from is corrupted.

Third, try to boot something else than Ubuntu. "Gparted LiveCD" is my go to solution. Be mindful of difference between Legacy Boot and UEFI boot mode though.

Fourth, try plugging USB stick in the top left USB port on your PC back. It is, so to speak, "port №1" and some rare motherboards can't boot from anything else.

Comment: Ty for your answer, I figured it out that it's a problem with the files of the stick. That erros says thst it can't mount de/loop to //.., those files arr in the USB content. I was thinking to burn an DVD but I'm afraid it can happens the same. I will try to talk to a friend to boot the USB for me on his windows machine with rufus. On mac it fails me..

Comment: Re-download your Ubuntu too.

Comment: I made a hash check on the .iso file and everything was ok..

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps provide in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/827431/29012 .  If you follow the steps closely this will have you up and running within 10 minutes.

To correct any changes you have made to your BIOS, first make sure your bios is set at the default.  When you go into the BIO's look for the option to set BIO's at it's default.

The only change that you would have to verify is that you you have Secure Boot disabled.  The default should have UEFI enabled.  Make sure it's enabled.

When you get to the "Try Ubuntu" option, hit `e` and specify `nomodeset` on the GRUB_CMDLINE.

Run the `Install Ubuntu` application from the desktop.  If you run into any problems you can copy and paste any details you see no the screen here.

Since you have said you don't have any OS on the drive, you can use the default option to use the whole drive for the installation.  The installer will do everything for you.

Comment: Thanks James, but from the error lines I saw there, the problem is with USB files, not with the bios. I already tried to add `nomodeset`, but after that I got the error. I will try to talk to a friend with win to reboot the usb with rufus

Comment: In conjunction with talking to your friend, did you perform the step to verify your BIOS is set at the defaults, by going into the BIOS and setting it?  Changes in the BIOS affect being able to boot to a media regardless of how it's made.  You have said you have made a number of Install USB.  Can you check if the USB can be booted to a different computer.

Comment: Resetes default, checked the secure boot option, added `nomodeset`,  this is what I got.. http://i.imgur.com/7OSQqzuh.jpg The USB might be corupted..